Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::appends() not found error in Laravel Blade view
for a laravel project, in the dashboard I have several pages (services, products, projects, clients....etc) services it has the cruds of services and projects has the cruds of projects and so on).
In some pages I have this error:

Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::appends does not
exist. (View:
C:\laragon\www\newdashboard\resources\views\admin\services\index.blade.php

while this page works correctly despite the fact that they have the same code.
Here is an example of a page that does not work:
ServiceController :
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Service;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;

class ServiceController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $filter = $request->get('search_input');
        $services = Service::search($filter)->paginate(20);
        //$types = Type::get();
        //dd($clients);
        return view('admin.services.index', compact('services', 'filter'));
    }

Models/Service.php :
class Service extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'subtitle',
        'description',
        'image'
        
    ];

    public function scopeSearch($query, $filter)
    {
        return $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $filter . '%');
    }
}

in the view I have a table with a foreach and at the bottom:
<div class="card-footer with-pagination">
      {{ $services->appends(['filter' => $filter])->links('vendor.pagination.bulma') }}
    </div>

and here is the code for a page that works correctly:
PortfolioController.php :
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Portfolio;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;

class PortfolioController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $filter = $request->get('search_input');
        $projects = Portfolio::search($filter)->paginate(20);
        //$types = Type::get();
        //dd($clients);
        return view('admin.projects.index', compact('projects', 'filter'));
    }

Models/Portfolio.php:
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Portfolio extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'short_desc',
        'desc',
        'image',
        'cat_id',
        'additional',
        'faq',
        
    ];

    public function scopeSearch($query, $filter)
    {
        return $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $filter . '%');
    }
}

and in the view the same a table with foreach and at the bottom:
    <div class="card-footer with-pagination">
      {{ $projects->appends(['filter' => $filter])->links('vendor.pagination.bulma') }}
    </div>

can anyone help me correct the error? any way, even if I have to change the code completely. or help me find where the error is coming from.
I tried to import classes such as:
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;


and other classes too and I tried in the view links instead of appends:
{{ $technologies->links() }}

but I don't think that's the problem. because in the other pages it works without changing anything. it's too weird.

If you take out the appends, do you get a similar error on links()? Are you using $services anywhere above the footer? It's odd that $services is a Collection instead of a LengthAwarePaginator

yes I have the same error with links, yes I too found it strange. it is not normal .

Are you using $services anywhere in the page above the footer, that would change the variable?

No that’s the issue, when I do dump and die on the controller it says it’s a LengthAwarePaginator but when it reaches the view it becomes a collection.
